# log4j2 (2.6.2) configuration not deleting old log files

Tags: log4j2

I have the following log4j2 xml configuration that I'm using to log TRACE and DEBUG level messages.

```
<Configuration status="WARN" packages="" monitorInterval="300">
  <Properties> 
    <Property name="log-path">/logs/webapp</Property> 
  </Properties> 

  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="TRACE" append="true" immediateFlush="true" fileName="${log-path}/trace.log" filePattern="${log-path}/trace.log.%d{MM-dd-yyyy}">
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%d{DEFAULT}: %-20C{1} : %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        <Delete basePath="${log-path}" maxDepth="1">
          <IfFileName glob="*/trace.log.*" />
          <IfLastModified age="14d" />
        </Delete>
      </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>

    <RollingFile name="DETAIL" append="true" immediateFlush="true" fileName="${log-path}/detail.log" filePattern="${log-path}/detail.log.%d{MM-dd-yyyy}">
      <PatternLayout> 
        <pattern>%d{DEFAULT}: %-20C{1} : %m%n</pattern> 
      </PatternLayout> 
      <Policies> 
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy /> 
      </Policies> 
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="15"/> 
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="TRACE" level="trace"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="DETAIL" level="debug"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The intention for this configuration is that the trace log files 14 days and older would be deleted but this is not the case. I have much older trace log files on my system still, the oldest being trace.log.11-02-2016

I'm aware of file deletion issues in log4j2 up to version 2.5 and 2.5 introduced the Delete configuration element but I am using 2.6.2.

Has anyone come across this and been able to get it to work either via an implementation version update or a configuration change?